# Maintaining time order in an asynchronous multi threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, design-patterns

I have a stream of stock prices for 1000 different stocks arriving from the exchange into my code. Due to the very high number of updates I need to use a multithreaded environment to process the price updates.

In a simple world I would have one job queue and a set of worker threads processing the queue. In the real world, however, I can't do this as I need to maintain the time order of updates for individual stocks.

A simple solution would be to use a hashing algorithm that allocated a specific stock to the same thread each time an update was seen. Unfortunately if I do this  means that I need to understand the update rates of each of my stocks to ensure my threads are kept busy (update rates are not constant for each stock). If I don't some threads could be saturated whilst others are idle.

Does anyone know of a pattern that caters for this problem?

Comment: Generally speaking "asynchronous" and "maintain order" are 2 conflicting requirements. Wouldn't you be better off using a specific tool like lmax disruptor for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why? Let me have a look at the lmax disruptor

Comment: Not sure you understand what? How asynchronousness affects ordering? Once you have multiple threads involved, any order needs to be actively maintained, increasing complexity.

Comment: A possible solution is to use the hashing algorithm you mentioned above and have the thread do very little work at first (e.g. update a timestamp-to-stock-transaction-id map). Once you have the time order stored, you can them offload the real work to another common thread-pool, which could process any transaction for any stock. When times comes to respect the time ordering, that code could then use the mapping that was created earlier